# Shouldn't this site have an open-source tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have noticed a couple of questions related to open-source software. I think it would be a good idea to create the tag for easier categorisation. I am aware that there are special tags for open-source programs, but I think it would be good to group all of them together.

I think [open-source](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) would do fine, but if you think something else would be better, please leave an answer. (Also leave an answer if you disagree.)

Comment: I thought that early on we did have an open-source tag (I seem to remember it in the earliest days). Perhaps someone manually moved everything into software when there was that push to combine things like "functionals", "meta-gga", into "density-functional-theory" ?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Tyberius, we now have 7 questions in the [open-source](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) tag.

I felt indifferent about having a tag for open-source-software, because there was already the software tag, and I couldn't see *myself* subscribing to a separate tag for open-source-software or commercial-software or free proprietary-freeware. But if it helps others, I don't see much harm in having the tag.

Furthermore, now that we have 7 threads in the open-source tag, we're able to see something that wasn't brought up in the question: this tag can also be applied for open-source databases or open-sorce information in general (not just software), so perhaps more people will use this tag than I originally thought.

Answer (score 0):

I think that tags should represent the question subject itself, not something related to the question.

I mean, if I have a question about a package error, this have nothing to do with the type of license the package have (even if the package IS open-source). On the other hand, if I want to release a package/script and don't know what type of license to use, the tags looks appropriated.

Comment: In the same spirit, we must get rid of [tag:software] then, I guess.

Comment: For me, it's quite different: you can have a question about theory or a question about a particular issue with a package.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand that. The usage of software says *For questions about materials modeling software. Questions can be about usage or recommendations.* What does this have to do with theory? The current usage of open-source says *For questions seeking open source software or databases to solve a modeling problem.* These uses are basically identical, only with a slightly different target.

Comment: I don't think the open source tag would be applied to a question just because the software being asked about it open source. Rather, I picture it being used for software/database recommendations where the user is indifferent to the program to use besides wanting to avoid licensing fees or the inability to use the program for specific purposes.